# Application Domain lifecycle difference between xamarin.android and xamarin.windows

Tags: c#, static, mono, xamarin.android, appdomain

I am used to the [Windows processes and threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841(v=vs.85).aspx) model. As a .NET developer I am familiar with the [Application Domains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs(v=vs.110).aspx). I've read about the [Android processes and threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Are there any noticeable differences in the AppDomain life time between the xamarin.android and xamarin.windows app? Do I need to do something about statis resources I declare and maintain in my xamarin.windows app when it is prepared to run as xamarin.android app? I see it is a broad question but I need a start.

Comment: You should dig into Google Android documentation for that kind of knowledge. Mobile apps have more status such as suspended and so on, which desktop apps don't.